# DB grid not displaying column width correctly

Tags: sql, delphi, dbgrid

I use DB Grids to display data, the problem is that the size of the columns are super inconsistent, and are in some cases way to big. Here I have a Db grid, width 450 displaying a field Player Name that in my access document is set to field size 20.

[image: 2 Db grids displaying the same field, but different sizes.]

[image: My database]

As you can see the same field is shown, but displayed differently in the dbGrids.
I have tried setting the size of the dbgrids columns manually by running this code:

```
DbGrid1.columns[0].width := 80;
```

But when I run this nothing happens, nothing is adjusted.
The DbGrids are connected to datasources that are connected to ADO queries running SELECT statements with SQL. SQL code for left DB Grid:

```
 sSQL := 'SELECT PlayerName , PlayerSurname, GamesPlayed, GoalsScored, ' +
      'ROUND(GoalsScored/GamesPlayed ,2) AS GoalsPerGame ' +
      'FROM tblPlayers , tblStatistics ' +
      'WHERE tblPlayers.PlayerID = tblStatistics.PlayerID ' +
      'AND GamesPlayed <> 0 ' + 'UNION  ' +
      'SELECT PlayerName, PlayerSurname, GamesPlayed, GoalsScored, 0  ' +
      'FROM tblPlayers , tblStatistics ' +
      'WHERE tblPlayers.PlayerID = tblStatistics.PlayerID ' +
      'AND GamesPlayed = 0 ' + 'ORDER BY GoalsScored DESC';
```

I run this SQL statement.
SQL statement for right dbGrid:

```
qryStatistics.SQL.Add
      ('SELECT PlayerName, PlayerSurname, PlayerSchoolID, GamesPlayed, GoalsScored, PlayerPosition  FROM tblStatistics, tblPlayers WHERE tblStatistics.PlayerID = tblPlayers.PlayerID');
```

The dbGrids dfm file looks like this:

```
object dbgScheduleS: TDBGrid
          Left = 40
          Top = 208
          Width = 609
          Height = 417
          DataSource = DM_Sport.dscSchedule
          ReadOnly = True
          TabOrder = 0
          TitleFont.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
          TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
          TitleFont.Height = -11
          TitleFont.Name = 'Segoe Print'
          TitleFont.Style = []
```

Do you know how to set the size of these columns?

Comment: May be the UNION is the culprit?

Comment: What does your `DBGrid1` (if that is the one with the problem) object look like in the `.dfm` file?

Comment: I have no idea what a .dfm file is @TomBrunberg. Ive looked where my project is stored and can't find it.

Comment: @UweRaabe I reckon that could be the problem, thing is that I have no way around that.

Comment: Every unit that defines a form has a companion file with the same name but with a `.dfm` ending if the project is a VCL project or `.fmx` if the project is a FMX (Firemonkey) project. These `.dfm`(or `.fmx`) files holds the structure and set properties of the form and its components. I assumed your project is a VCL project but if it is a FMX project, then the content of the `.fmx` is what I am asking about.

Comment: You can set DisplayWidth of the field.

Comment: In the SQL statement? @UweRaabe

Comment: Still haven't found the `.dfm` (or `.fmx`)  file?

Comment: Sorry man @TomBrunberg, I was looking for a .dfm extension and couldn't find it, but I did find it like a couple seconds ago. Must I just attach the screen shot of the dbgrid in the dfm file in my question?

Comment: @TomBrunberg I added what it said there to my question.

Comment: I think I did what you said to do, check the bottom of the question.

Comment: Ok, now look still in the `.dfm` at your datasource's fields for `DisplayWidth` numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort man, but I am not able to find anything to do with display width in either my main VCL form, or in my datamodule. I am just going to leave it, its only a school project, so I will be like docked 1 point max.

Comment: Can you change the SQL to this?
SELECT PlayerName , PlayerSurname, GamesPlayed, GoalsScored, 
IIF(GamesPlayed = 0, 0, ROUND(GoalsScored/GamesPlayed ,2)) AS GoalsPerGame 
FROM tblPlayers , tblStatistics 
WHERE tblPlayers.PlayerID = tblStatistics.PlayerID 
ORDER BY GoalsScored DESC

Comment: That SQL change somehow fixed it, Thank you so much!

Comment: Please write an answer - you can answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my SQL statement, it seems like the UNION is what messed it up.
The correct SQL was:

```
sSQL := 'SELECT PlayerName , PlayerSurname, GamesPlayed, GoalsScored, IIF(GamesPlayed = 0, 0, ROUND(GoalsScored/GamesPlayed ,2)) AS GoalsPerGame FROM tblPlayers , tblStatistics WHERE tblPlayers.PlayerID = tblStatistics.PlayerID ORDER BY GoalsScored DESC';
```

I still don't know how to change the column sizes after creating columns with the TADOQry, connected to a datasource, displaying to a dbGrid.